# How to split a Webix datatable column into multiple columns?

Tags: datatable, webix

In my *webix* datatable, I am showing multiple values in the cells for some columns.

To identify which values belong to which header, I have separated the column headers by a `'|'` (pipe) and similarly the values under them as well.

Now, in place of delimiting the columns by `'|'` , I need to split the columns into some editable columns with the same name.

Please refer to this snippet : https://webix.com/snippet/8ce1148e 
In this above snippet, for example the `Scores` column will be split into two more editable columns as `Rank` and `Vote`. Similarly for `Place` column into `Type` and `Name`.

How the values of the first array elements is shown under each of them will remain as is.

How can this be done ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While creating the column configuration for webix, you can provide array to the header field for the first column along with the colspan like below:

`var columns = [];`
`columns[0] =`
`{"id":"From", "header":[{"text":"Date","colspan":2},{"text":"From"}]};`

`columns[1] =`
`{"id":"To","header":[null, {"text":"To"}]};`

`column[0] will create Date and From and column[1] will be creating the To.`

Comment: I am already using 'header', could you please show me in  the snippet exactly how you are suggesting ?

Comment: Please see the updated answer, in case you still have any query please revert me back.

Comment: I tried it the way you suggested , but it is not giving me the desired result, see here please : https://webix.com/snippet/fdb7378d

Comment: Please fidn below the url:https://webix.com/snippet/8bfdf669, you just need to apply the css to display header in center (there is a css property in header just give css='xyz' in the header)

Comment: You can also follow the below url, if you want headers in center too:https://webix.com/snippet/8384ae1c

Comment: Could you please tell me what is this 'null' in "header":[null, {"text":"To"}] ..Because I am facing a problem as when I write something under those editable header cells , the values are disappearing. Then again when I click on the cell, I see those values. I am sorry I could not make a snippet of it to show. But can this happen ? What could be the probable reason for that? is it that 'null' thing?

Comment: Well I am facing this when I use template function hence making another post to show it. Kindly look into it.

Comment: Could you please share the link to another post So that I can check the issue, which you are facing?. I have created multiple applications by using the same, So there might be some small issue, Please share the link I can look into that.